# Inconsistent "Pinned Sites" sync

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, communities-list

"Pinned Sites" in the iOS app and the "Your Communities" list on the main site should sync.

The list currently only syncs from the app to the main site, not the other way round. So any changes I make on the site only affect the list on the site, which means I have different sites pinned on the app and the site. If I make any changes on the app though, it is updated on the site.

This all started when I installed the beta, which reverted my pinned sites to an old previous state. Not sure if that is a bug or just a result of switching from the production release to beta—but I'm not too worried about that.

---

- App Version: 1.6.0.7
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's synchronized, but not in real time. Give it some time and see. (e.g. one hour.)

Comment: It definitely was until I installed the beta, and it's instant app to site, but it's not updating at all the other way round (it's been a good few hours).

Comment: hmm.... well then, let Brian do his magic and see what's going on. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.8.

As a consequence of a major refactoring, the pinned sites were only getting read at login rather than login and launch.  I've updated it so the app will fetch the pinned site list every time the app becomes active.